# Google Sheets - Query returns a header row?

Tags: google-sheets

sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scZ_jlw6Wx1xH3gQ_z9rBAadyw6WxqcbFk10VQIDjHk/edit#gid=1644909572)

I have been using QUERY() for a sometime, but never faced this.

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE({INDIRECT(B10)}),"select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col5='"&A10&"' order by Col2")
```

The result is as expected except the top row which does NOT conform to the WHERE clause and appears to the first Non-Empty row in the data-range.

In the sample, the anomalous row is red colored, and the expected rows are green colored.

I also found that each empty cell as added to this anomalous row as a single SPACE character. In the sample, there is one space before the text and 14 spaces after the text in the anomalous row.

What am doing wrong?

EDIT: While the above issue remains, for my purpose I found a work around as below. That is, sort the data range before applying the query, ensuring ALL data rows come before the empty rows.

```
=QUERY(SORT(TRANSPOSE({INDIRECT(B10)}),2,TRUE),"select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col5='"&A10&"' order by Col2")
```

Comment: Yes it works for $Q$1 - but I cannot fix it like that for my case. Besides, its expected the QUERY() WHERE clause will wean out all empty rows in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if adding the (optional) headers argument (set to zero) helps

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE({INDIRECT(B10)}),"select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col5='"&A10&"' order by Col2",0)
```